# how to get data for particular row of table in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a table that has got 3 rows,

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas; let i = index" (click)="getSupplier(data.id)">
    <td>{{ data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ data.id}}</td>
    <td>
       <select [disabled]="i == selectedRow? false : true">
          <option *ngFor="let supplier of supplierData">{{supplier.supplierName}}</option>
       </select>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

On page load expect select dropdown all other data is populating correctly, and once user click on the row then corresponding data should populate for select dropdown.

Below is the code for populating select dropdown:

```
getSuppliers(id){
  this._BOMService.getSupplier(id).subscribe(data => this.supplierData = data);
```

}

But once the user clicks the row, data is populating for all other rows too in the table which should not happen.

Please help me by guiding how should to fix the issue so that data for select dropdown comes for selected row only.

Comment: can you create stackblitz to show the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign the selected row to i?

```
    <tr *ngFor="let data of datas; let i = index" (click)="selectedRow=i;getSupplier(data.id)">
    //code
    </tr>
```